# Counterexample to closures of sets and its limit points.

Tags: general-topology

I need find an example of a topological space such that $ \overline{A} \subset \overline{B} $ but $ A^a \not \subset B^a $. $ A^a $ means the accumulation points of $ A $. Any hints on this? I was hoping to find a simple one in the usual topology, but my guess is I probably need a funkier topology.

Comment: I am assuming that your space is Hausdorff. In that case $A^{a} \subset B^{a}$, unless your definition of accumulation point is different from mine!

Comment: does it help if I say $ \overline{A} = A \cup A^a $? I believe an equivalent definition is that an accumulation is a limit point. I need to find a topological space which breaks the fact that closure is contained but not limit points

Answer (score 1):

Take the space $\{0,1\}$ equipped with the trivial topology. Let $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{0\}$. Then $ \overline{A} = \overline{B} = \{0,1\}$ but $A^a \not \subseteq B^a$ since $0 \in A^a$ but  $0 \notin B^a$.